# Повторное выполнение метода ,если метод не отработал

Tags: java

вообщем суть вопроса такова
есть метод который принимает из консоли координаты,если координаты не валидны выкидывает исключение и выходит из работы
а нужно чтобы пока метод работал до тех пор,пока не отработал бы

сам код выглядит так вот 
метод

```
 case 3:
               System.out.println("Ход белого игрока");
               System.out.println("Введите координату в формате e2-a4");
               Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
               String sss2=sc2.nextLine();



              while( menu.executeMenu(White,sss2)){
                  menu.executeMenu(White,sc2.nextLine());
              }


               System.out.println("Ход черного игрока");
               System.out.println("Введите координату в формате e2-a4");
               String sss3=sc2.nextLine();
                menu.executeMenu(Black,sss3);


             break;
```

это игра шахматы ,вообщем игрок один делает ход,потом второй
и все бы хорошо ,но если координаты не верные вводятся то вместо того чтобы запросить их еще раз программа переходит к ходу второго игрока

подскажите может концепцию общую как это реализовать

1.шаг принмает координаты
2.передаем их в метод -если метод отработал передаем их ниже если нет возвращаемся в пункт 2 до тех пор пока метод не отработает
сам метод сделал возвращающим булевое значение

```
public boolean executeMenu(Gamer gamer, String s) {
        try {
            String from = s.split("-", 2)[0].toLowerCase();
            String to = s.split("-", 2)[1].toLowerCase();
            Postition a = new Postition(Interpritator.reverseInter(from).get(0), Interpritator.reverseInter(from).get(1));
            Postition b = new Postition(Interpritator.reverseInter(to).get(0), Interpritator.reverseInter(to).get(1));


            if (Game.validEat(a, b) && gamer.checkGamerColor(Field.getFigure(a.getX(), a.getY()))) {
                gamer.eatFigure(a, b);
                print();
                return false;
            } else if (Game.validMove(a, b) && gamer.checkGamerColor(Field.getFigure(a.getX(), a.getY()))) {
                gamer.moveFigure(a, b);


                print();
                return false;
            } else System.err.println("Ход не доступен");



            // else System.err.println("Эта фигура не вашего цвета");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Вводи правильные координаты ");

        }
 return false;

    }
```

Comment: Вам нужен метод, проверяющий правильность координат. Ему пераем координаты, он проверяет их валидность. Если ход валидный - выполнить ход на доске и передать ход другому игроку, если нет - повторить запрос снова

Comment: так какая разница что циклить? данный метод у меня тоже проверяет валидность и сразу ее отрабатывает .тут вся проблема в том,как заставить программу выполнять метод до тех пор ,пока он не перестанет исключения кидать.

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав когда нужно что-то зациклить, очевидно нужно использовать цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true){
    try {
       String inputLine = sc.nextLine();
       // То, что может вызвать ошибку
       break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      /* Можно предупредить, что некорректные входные данные */
    }
}
```

В бесконечном цикле выполняем операцию в блоке try-catch, и если try успешно отработал, то цикл остановить.

Можно так:

```
void thatMethod() {
    try {
       String inputLine = sc.nextLine();
       // То, что может вызвать ошибку
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* Можно предупредить, что некорректные входные данные */
        thatMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: ни первый ни второй вариант не пработают

Comment: 1й вариант делает один раз круг и просто программа завершается

Comment: второй вариант не применим ,так как этот метод принимает аргументы и их нужно получить,прежде чем передать тоесть тоже не подходит вариант

Comment: Грубо говоря мне нужно зациклить выполнение работы метода-если метод кидает исключение -повторить не кидает выйти из цикла

Comment: В последнем варианте настойчивый игрок может довести игру до stackoverlow:)

Answer (score 0):

вообщем такое решение этого вопроса вот в такой конструкции

в такой констркции метод будет исполняться до тех пор ,пока не выполнится без ошибок- кому надо берите на вооружение

```
bolean b;
do
{
    try
    {
        b=false
    }
    catch
    {
        b=true
    }
}
while(true)
```